# Resizing report to bigger size

Tags: crystal-reports, resize

This may seem like a stupid question, but I've been looking everywhere to fix this problem and can't seem to find the solution.

So i have a report that is set to a landscape size: 8.5"x11" and i want to set the report to be a legal size: 8.5"x14".

I have gone to page setup and turned on no printer as well as dissociate formatting page size and i have set the page to legal and changed the dimensions to 8.5"x14".

My problem is that the change only shows up in preview mode and i am unable to move the position of the fields in my report in the newly expanded width. So i would like to know if there is a way to change the size of a report in design view or how to position fields outside of the 8.5"x11" dimensions. Or is this not possible?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest answer I can give you:

Load a PDF printer driver.  My favorite is CutePDF (except I am ashamed to recommend it at the office... I usually recommend the "MyPrettyPonyPDF").

Once this is loaded, it will look like you have an additional "printer" available.  When you select the PDF Driver as printer, you'll have a large selection of add'l page sizes to choose from.  The printer I have available has 13 defined paper sizes.  With the CutePDF driver, I have 50 defined page sizes.  The largest I see is 36in x 108in -- and when you orient that in Landscape, you can camp on it.

Comment: +1 for additional paper sizes, and also "MyPrettyPonyPDF". :))

Answer (score 0):

Check your margins. The margin area doesn't show up in the Design tab, but would display on the Preview tab. If 'Adjust Automatically' for margins is set, Crystal will just make your margins huge when you dissociate the paper sizes and then increase the horizontal/vertical manually.

Try deselecting 'Adjust Automatically' under the 'Margins' settings, then set 'No Printer', then select a legal paper size. Double check the margins are the size you want and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer I can think of: try unchecking the `No Printer` option, set the layout and paper size to Landscape and Legal, and *then* set the `No Printer` option on again.